benchmarking exceptions vs error by value
I've decided to measure the performance difference between 2 approaches for handling errors:

return by value (sum of errors)
throw

I've written a simple benchmark for calculating a sum of a large array of integers.
By design, there may be 2 types of errors: err_a and err_b. For returning by value I am using std::variant (I'd use std::expected, but I'm more interested in C++17).
Here's the whole program:
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

#include <random>

#include <variant>
#include <vector>

namespace {

constexpr int k_err_a_value = 8;
constexpr int k_err_b_value = 15;

struct err_a {};
struct err_b {};

[[maybe_unused]] std::variant<int, err_a, err_b>
sum_raw(const std::vector<int> &v) {
  for (const auto &i : v) {
    if (k_err_a_value == i)
      return {err_a{}};
  }

  for (const auto &i : v) {
    if (k_err_b_value == i)
      return {err_b{}};
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for (int i: v)
    sum += i;

  return {sum};
}

[[maybe_unused]] int sum_exceptions(const std::vector<int> &v) {
  for (const auto &i : v) {
    if (k_err_a_value == i)
      throw err_a{};
  }

  for (const auto &i : v) {
    if (k_err_b_value == i)
      throw err_b{};
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for (int i: v)
    sum += i;

  return sum;
}

std::vector<int> generate(const size_t n, const double err_perc,
                          bool use_err_b) {
  std::mt19937 gen32;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<decltype(gen32)::result_type> dist{};
  std::vector<int> generated;
  generated.reserve(n);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    auto g = dist(gen32);
    while (k_err_a_value == g || k_err_b_value == g)
      g = dist(gen32);
    generated.emplace_back(g);
  }

  if (err_perc <= 100.0)
    generated[n / 100.0 * err_perc] = use_err_b ? k_err_b_value : k_err_a_value;

  return generated;
}

class bm_sum : public ::benchmark::Fixture {
public:
  void SetUp(benchmark::State &state) override {
    const size_t elems = state.range(0);
    const double err_perc = state.range(1);
    const bool use_err_b = state.range(2);

    _generated = generate(elems, err_perc, use_err_b);
  }

  const std::vector<int> &generated() const { return _generated; }

  constexpr static int
  from_variant(std::variant<int, err_a, err_b> v) noexcept {
    return std::visit([](auto i) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(i), int>)
            return i;
        else
            return 0;
    }, std::move(v));
  }

private:
  std::vector<int> _generated;
};

BENCHMARK_DEFINE_F(bm_sum, raw)(benchmark::State &state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(from_variant(sum_raw(generated())));
    benchmark::ClobberMemory();
  }
}

BENCHMARK_DEFINE_F(bm_sum, exceptions)(benchmark::State &state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize([&] {
      try {
        return sum_exceptions(generated());
      } catch (...) {
        return 0;
      }
    }());
    benchmark::ClobberMemory();
  }
}

// todo: how not to repeat?
BENCHMARK_REGISTER_F(bm_sum, raw)
    ->ArgsProduct({benchmark::CreateRange(1'000, 10'000'000, 10),
                   {101, 80}, // perc of range where to put error
                   {0, 1}});  // which error to put
BENCHMARK_REGISTER_F(bm_sum, exceptions)
    ->ArgsProduct({benchmark::CreateRange(1'000, 10'000'000, 10),
                   {101, 80}, // perc of range where to put error
                   {0, 1}});  // which error to put

} // namespace

BENCHMARK_MAIN();


https://godbolt.org/z/qvKjhsqeq (unfortunatelly godbolt times out, and quickbench gives me 504).
On my local machine I have the following results:
./sb.benchmark --benchmark_perf_counters=cycles,cache-misses --benchmark_counters_tabular=true
2024-04-19T23:35:59+02:00
Running ./sb.benchmark
Run on (14 X 2496 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 48 KiB (x7)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x7)
  L2 Unified 1280 KiB (x7)
  L3 Unified 24576 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 0.10, 0.09, 0.13
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                 Time             CPU   Iterations cache-misses     cycles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bm_sum/raw/1000/101/0                  1069 ns         1069 ns       636442     2.51555m   4.91236k
bm_sum/raw/10000/101/0                10586 ns        10586 ns        60632    0.0602157   48.7407k
bm_sum/raw/100000/101/0              106081 ns       106081 ns         6309      3.38136   490.177k
bm_sum/raw/1000000/101/0            1090694 ns      1090673 ns          643      86.4121   4.95838M
bm_sum/raw/10000000/101/0          12747631 ns     12747661 ns           56     728.965k   57.4208M
bm_sum/raw/1000/80/0                    305 ns          305 ns      2305042     832.523u   1.37914k
bm_sum/raw/10000/80/0                  3007 ns         3007 ns       234384    0.0165071   13.6091k
bm_sum/raw/100000/80/0                29853 ns        29853 ns        22999     0.789817    136.49k
bm_sum/raw/1000000/80/0              304049 ns       304021 ns         2253      17.3751   1.38246M
bm_sum/raw/10000000/80/0            3475828 ns      3475840 ns          203     157.936k   15.6962M
bm_sum/raw/1000/101/1                  1085 ns         1085 ns       642429     2.44541m   4.90695k
bm_sum/raw/10000/101/1                10707 ns        10707 ns        65729    0.0729663   48.5398k
bm_sum/raw/100000/101/1              107129 ns       107129 ns         6491      3.93329   491.078k
bm_sum/raw/1000000/101/1            1088631 ns      1088582 ns          638      91.7288   4.95532M
bm_sum/raw/10000000/101/1          12643454 ns     12643180 ns           55     662.523k   57.2454M
bm_sum/raw/1000/80/1                    689 ns          689 ns      1020652     1.82432m    3.0944k
bm_sum/raw/10000/80/1                  6868 ns         6827 ns       104038    0.0540476   30.6999k
bm_sum/raw/100000/80/1                68330 ns        68328 ns        10139      1.53684   307.825k
bm_sum/raw/1000000/80/1              699654 ns       699641 ns         1001      48.8442   3.13284M
bm_sum/raw/10000000/80/1            7940662 ns      7940478 ns           89     401.665k    35.645M
bm_sum/exceptions/1000/101/0           1059 ns         1059 ns       667015     1.49322m   4.77571k
bm_sum/exceptions/10000/101/0         10546 ns        10448 ns        67843     0.059505   47.2691k
bm_sum/exceptions/100000/101/0       106142 ns       106134 ns         6705      3.05921   476.693k
bm_sum/exceptions/1000000/101/0     1078165 ns      1078167 ns          627      91.6794   4.82523M
bm_sum/exceptions/10000000/101/0   12818019 ns     12818064 ns           56     778.332k   56.6963M
bm_sum/exceptions/1000/80/0            1012 ns         1012 ns       711029    0.0154776   4.30537k
bm_sum/exceptions/10000/80/0           4063 ns         4063 ns       171986    0.0489691   18.0548k
bm_sum/exceptions/100000/80/0         35108 ns        35107 ns        19991      1.71187   156.273k
bm_sum/exceptions/1000000/80/0       346133 ns       346107 ns         2025      25.8459    1.5448M
bm_sum/exceptions/10000000/80/0     3799323 ns      3799337 ns          186     149.998k   17.0065M
bm_sum/exceptions/1000/101/1           1151 ns         1138 ns       664848       7.331m    4.8899k
bm_sum/exceptions/10000/101/1         10440 ns        10439 ns        66535    0.0605546   47.3161k
bm_sum/exceptions/100000/101/1       107680 ns       107279 ns         6469      2.44025   475.383k
bm_sum/exceptions/1000000/101/1     1083270 ns      1083248 ns          656      86.6845   4.80974M
bm_sum/exceptions/10000000/101/1   12731712 ns     12731425 ns           55     793.803k   56.0746M
bm_sum/exceptions/1000/80/1            1352 ns         1352 ns       516954     0.017253    5.8567k
bm_sum/exceptions/10000/80/1           7257 ns         7257 ns        94411     0.123969   32.8961k
bm_sum/exceptions/100000/80/1         68093 ns        68091 ns        10372      3.50578   304.665k
bm_sum/exceptions/1000000/80/1       687979 ns       687981 ns         1048      113.377   3.07051M
bm_sum/exceptions/10000000/80/1     7798697 ns      7798521 ns           87     470.073k   35.5996M

g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

As can be seen, when no exceptions are thrown (101), the performance is apparently almost identical. However, the interesting part was for when exceptions are thrown (at 80% of input processed).
For small inputs the result is as expected, exceptions are slower.
bm_sum/raw/1000/80/0                    305 ns          305 ns      2305042     832.523u   1.37914k
bm_sum/exceptions/1000/80/0            1012 ns         1012 ns       711029    0.0154776   4.30537k

But I've been expecting another level of magnitude here, not just 2-3 times slower.
However, the most surprising thing was on a large set:
bm_sum/raw/10000000/80/0            3475828 ns      3475840 ns          203     157.936k   15.6962M
bm_sum/exceptions/10000000/80/0     3799323 ns      3799337 ns          186     149.998k   17.0065M

bm_sum/raw/10000000/80/1            7940662 ns      7940478 ns           89     401.665k    35.645M
bm_sum/exceptions/10000000/80/1     7798697 ns      7798521 ns           87     470.073k   35.5996M

It appears that for a large enough data set, when exception is thrown at a later point, it can even be faster, than returning by value.
Do I observe reasonable effects here?
What minimalistic example can be made to show the actual disadvantage in performance with exceptions?
PS:
I believe having actual numbers performance-wise for such things (with actual code examples) is beneficial for many developers who want to participate in the holy war against exceptions.

I never realized we had a HOLY war against exceptions! a small grudge, yes but I like your post.

Additionally, the main advantage of exceptions is, again, not performance -- it's the fact that your error-path doesn't clutter the happy flow. I can completely ignore errors, unless I'm on a layer where I want to handle some or all of them.

And don't forget this maxim: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. If your profiling shows that error handling is actually a bottleneck in your application, then think about benchmarking it.

@SergeyKolesnik yeah, but that's not really my concern. Think about the guy sending these requests -- they setup the RPC, send it to me, wait for response, and all they get is "error". They have way more incentive to fix their stuff than I have to speed up my exception handling...

I deleted all but the "root of all evil" comment.

How are you compiling your code? Whether or not compiler optimizations (and link-time optimizations) are enabled or not (and at what level) can have a serious impact. And especially; if the code is compiled without optimization, then all measurements are irrelevant.

There are multiple implementation for exception and a usual one is the zero cost exceptions (ZCE), but Zero-cost exceptions aren’t actually zero cost. As said in the article, ZCE has a "significantly higher cost for throwing an exception". This is an expect behaviour in nearly all programs since exception are meant to be use for... well... exceptional use-cases. If they are not, then something is clearly wrong in the design of your application. For cases that can usually fail, error code are the way to go.

If you still want to use exception when they are not intended to be used, that is in non-exceptional use-cases, then you should certainly try enabling the other exception model (if available on your target platform), and profile it. But again: having this in your application is certainly an evidence of a design design flaw (which should be fixed).

@JérômeRichard this code is compiled with -O3 and default exception model used by gcc. Again, "exceptional" is such a common argument, but nobody ever provides any numbers of what is considered exceptional (1/1000 invocations? 1/million?). And why does std have a lot of "unexceptional" exceptions? Anyway, I'm familiar with your argument and with several answers about ZCE. But they all claim 20-30 times slower execution when exception is thrown. This is not shown by the benchmark. Hence the question

@JesperJuhl you could open the godbolt link and see what flags are used (-O3). Lto here will not give anything since it is a single transaction unit, the functions are in anonymous namespace and have internal linkage

@SergeyKolesnik AFAIK GCC use this model by default. Zero cost exceptions are now the mainstream implementation because users generally do not expect exceptions to slow down normal execution paths. It looks like GCC support 2 models and the other one is not zero-cost exception so It might be interesting to test the performance of the other model.

@SergeyKolesnik Regarding exceptional use-case, it is not much about frequency (<0.1%) but whether the use-case is abnormal or not / a critical unexpected error. Actually an error use-case as defined in in UML modeling. For example not having enough memory is a good example (both critical and unexpected). Exception might be good or bad for errors like parsing errors or look-ups regarding your application. For example, if you try to parse a float and then an integer when the former fail because you want to support both (normal) cases then this is a design flaw to use exceptions for that.

@JérômeRichard regardless, there's no consensus about what constitutes an exceptional scenario. Lack of memory is not considered an exceptional case, it is basically unrecoverable. You also wouldn't use exceptions for developer errors (you'll use assert). The only case where everyone one agrees is RAII - a conventional way to report errors by throwing from a constructor. ... but erroneous input is not exceptional. So, again, its only your opinion. My question is about benchmarking - what scenarios and parameters to test. And compare the results to what is expected.

On a Ryzen 2600, I get a 5x difference between bm_sum/raw/1000/80/0 and bm_sum/exceptions/1000/80/0. For the large data sets, I get faster times for exceptions in both cases, however.

Note that libstdc++'s implementation of std::visit is known to be a bit slow (1, 2)

@LHLaurini I think the main point here would not be that "exceptions are X times slower", but in terms of some penalty like "throwing an exception costs up to 100 milliseconds". I believe that it is more informative for an educated decision on how to organize error handling. It's like knowing the times for data access inside cpu/ram/ssd. I think I should add some runtime polymorphism here for exceptions and see what effect it would have.

A "holy war", really? Never heard of it... An exception is for cases, precisely, EXCEPTIONAL. Any expected or frequent error case should NOT be handled via an exception, but rather through return codes and/or a known and planned fallback mode. Measuring the "performance" of an exception is not relevant, considering that in the normal flow of a program, there shouldn't be a SINGLE one thrown, and if exceptions are still thrown, it should be for cases where an "emergency stop" is required. And in such case, performance isn't relevant - who would dare to use exceptions in real-time context?

@Wisblade I think I have to address these kind of comments in the question in order not to repeat the same discussion all over again (not the first time, has been deleted already). "exceptional exceptions" is so vague that there're no 2 people that would have the same opinion on what constitutes exceptional. The standard library has the whole hierarchy of exceptions that don't seem to be "exceptional". And also no-one has ever provided actual numbers for "what is considered exceptional". 1 in million? billion invocations? So far no good point has been made. RAII is the only rationale

@SergeyKolesnik As I said, if it's frequent, expected or a planned fallback mode, exceptions aren't suitable. In fact, you should not throw your own exception without thinking about it carefully, but catch the ones thrown by what you call. AFAIC, I throw exception in cases of unrecoverable errors - caller's responsibility to catch it when he can recover it, and it's NEVER in critical-time code so performance isn't even a question. "Exceptional" is not a matter of raw number of calls, but a matter of occurences within product's lifetime - think about safety and "catastrophic" events.

@Wisblade it is just your opinion. "I throw exception in cases of unrecoverable errors" - out of memory is unrecoverable, but is commonly not considered an exception. Also a thrown exception does not mean "unrecoverable" because one can actually recover. Anyways, this question is not about "when to use exceptions", but "how much do they actually cost" and "what does this cost depend on". Similarly to understanding the data access time, one should be able to make an educated decision. Unless you can provide scenarios/parameters for benchmarking, no need to continue.

@SergeyKolesnik Unrecoverable is meant for a given application, not as an absolute rule - out of memory may, or may not, be unrecoverable… And it’s for a given workflow, it does NOT mean that you should exit app. And it’s a XY problem because exceptions should NOT be used for ALL planned / known / handled errors, or for time-critical workflows. When one is thrown, your workflow is disrupted, stopped and you go back to your preconditions, and the time it consumed is irrelevant since you’ll wait for user’s input or something similar each time - if not, then exceptions shouldn’t be used there.
